# PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager setMaxPerRoute(0) and setMaxTotal(0), what will happen?

Tags: httpclient, connection-pooling

Does someone know if I set　**MaxPerRoute** and **MaxTotal** of **PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager** to "0" like below, what will happen?

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxPerRoute(0)
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exception

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Max value may not be negative or zero");
```

for both methods, check the `org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool` class source code.